# Acer Touch pad not working

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I have Acer-TravelMate 5742 upgraded its Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, everything is fine but my Touch pad is not working.

Why Touch pad is not accepting clicks? How to fix it?

Comment: Would you accept your own answer as it is the one that works for you. It will help others find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

My laptop model is Acer-TravelMate 5742.
I change below file, it worked for me.

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d/
sudo vi options.conf
```

Then enter below text in that file.

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Save and close it. Run below two commands.

1. `sudo modprobe -r psmouse`
2. `sudo modprobe psmouse`